# Just to confirm about blueprism spying

Tags: blueprism

I want spy a item in browser which is not in specific area,it may change the area .need to search for it & click? Is it possible in blueprism?

Answer (score 0):

Basis responsiveness (browser/platform etc.) item in browser might be changing.

If your region has any **text** associated then while spying under match go for dynamic option from drop down, or under value column add the **text** with a wildcard * so it can be located precisely each and every time the application is launched.

Also do not forget to attach wait stages because spying on heavy sites takes time to sync.

Comment: If you could help attach screenshots

Answer (score -2):

It depends on the browser. In BP, they are working in the integration of Chrome and Firefox but... if its your case, it's better to Integrate  C# Selenium HQ into an Object in BP and then you can "spy" your elements (find elements) by ID, Name, etc.

```
If you are using IE, Blueprism can use different Spy modes (HTML, Accessibility or UI) the thing is that you need to use attributes that are not related to the position or size (id, name, tag name, etc)
```

Best Regards

Comment: This is massively out of line and not required. Very misleading to anyone looking for BluePrism advice to be told to to pull in a dependency on C# code